# Turn queue list into an embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Recently made a queue command for my bot and it works, but I'm wanting it to display in a RichEmbed.

```
let resp = `**Now Playing:**\n${nowPlaying.songTitle}\n**Requested By:**\n${nowPlaying.requester}\n\n**Queue**\n`


for (var i = 1; i < queue.length; i++) {
    resp += `${i}. **${queue[i].songTitle}**\n**Requested By:** ${queue[i].requester}\n`
}
```

This is the current code I have set to display the queue. Now, my exact problem is `resp +=`. I know that each time a song is added to the queue and the command is rerun, it will have it listed as it is in the queue, but I'm still teaching myself Node.JS, so this is a little more difficult to solve, as I've never had any commands that use `+=` to send an updated message.

Comment: @PruthviKumar Is it possible to take the `for loop` and put it into an embed though? That's my problem. Or is there some other way to implement it? The first part of it can easily fit inside an embed, but where it lists the rest of the songs in the queue, those are blow the embed.

Comment: What you get using `+=` is equivalent of string concatenation. eg: `let i = 'a'; i+='b';//results in i = 'ab'`. You can use this syntax anywhere. Just be mindful of how `+=` is overloaded in different scenarios

Comment: [Current code](https://pastebin.com/yybjMjnx)
Whenever I run that, I get
```[object Object]1. Artist - Songname
Requested By: Requester```

Comment: I sense some gap in what you are trying to do vs what you want to do. If I understand the issue correctly, you want to go through the loop and update `resp`? That way you will have `resp` reflecting only last items of your `queue`. What you are currently trying to do is concatenate `resp` . It will help if you describe what you want to achieve

Comment: [Here](https://gyazo.com/e32b9583093e14a247ea702309fbf6c7)
This is what I want sitting inside an embed. But I cant get the loop to be inside the embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let q = ``;
for(var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    q += `\n${i + 1}. **${queue[i].songTitle}**\nRequested By: ${queue[i].requester}`;
}
let resp = [
    {name: `Now Playing`, value: nowPlaying.songTitle},
    {name: `Requested By`, value: nowPlaying.requester},
    {name: `Queue`, value: q},
];

//Putting it all together
message.channel.send({embed: {
    title: 'Queue',
    fields: resp,
}});
```